# How to remove keys from array to create list of values only in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a method that passes in an array, and requires a list of `int` numbers separated by commas to be taken from the passed in array. When I pass in the array, I obviously see the `key=>value` relationship like:

```
0 => 38
1 => 39
2 => 40
3 => 41
```

But in my method, I need to remove the key for each item in the array, and build a literal list of int numbers - not a string - to be used in my method like the following:

```
[38, 39, 40, 41]
```

I can't do a `foreach` and simply echo each value, as my method only runs once and requires a literal list of `int`s followed by commas to be used further down deep in my method. When I iterate through the array to build a new array, keys are created there too. I can't simply pass in a string, as that would have quotes at the beginning and end of the string. I'm a bit confused how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try it with implode()?

Comment: $new_value = implode(',',$your_array);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: `I can't simply pass in a string, as that would have quotes at the beginning and end of the string` Quotes are not part of value it for php to compile and take value inside quotes.

Comment: please post you code

Comment: i wasn't using implode correctly. great! if you can formally answer i will accept.

Comment: Those 2 arrays in your question literally the same

Comment: `But in my method, I need to remove the key for each item in the array,` Can you show that `method` ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = [1,2,3,4];
$new_value = implode(',',$array);
```

Comment: i am curious about the DV :)

Answer (score -1):

Both your arrays are same, 
`[38, 39, 40, 41]`. Here `38` is at `index 0`, `39` at `1`. 
you can use `array_values` if you want to pick only array values or reset your index values if they are not aligned ie 0,1,2.
With `implode`, you will be converting your array to string which will not include `[ ]`. So you can pass your complete array as it is in your further methods.
  If you want to output it is a string `[38, 39, 40, 41]` then this can be achieved like this.

```html
   echo '['.implode(", ",$arr).']';
```